# How to approximate a function to Inegrate

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

How can I solve the following integral? or how can I approximate the function to solve the integral?

$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1 + (N\cdot A\cdot\sin(N\theta))^2}\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Comment: Is $N$ and $A$ just an integers?

Comment: yes those are constant.

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative is EllipticE[N theta, -A^2 N^2]/N and the result of the integration is EllipticE[2 N Pi, -A^2 N^2]/N where EllipticE[Phi,m] is the elliptic integral of the second kind. Have a look to

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind

Comment: parameters $A$ and $N$ are variable but they're constant and unknown. your method is useful for known parameters $A$ and $N$.

Comment: @SasanSamie. I do not see the point. What precisely do you want to do beside the integral ? Do you need to solve some equations ? Please precise for me. Thanks.

Comment: I mean that to find $E(k)$, $k$ must be an integer or a number. here in my problem $k$ is not a number. This integral is the result of equality of outer flange evironment before and after wrinkling in deep drawing